# Hive throwing ParseException while exporting a csv

Tags: sql, csv, hive, hiveql, hive-query

```
hive -e 'SELECT *, MIN(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS MIN_YEARLY, MAX(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_YEARLY, AVG(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS AVG_YEARLY, STDDEV(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS STD_YEARLY FROM NSEDATA ORDER BY SYMBOL;' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > ~/output2.csv
```

Running this code, I am trying to export a csv but I get the following error:

> ParseException line 2:3 cannot recognize input near 'MIN' '(' 'HIGH' in expression specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add table alias (`d`) and use `select d.*` instead of `select *`:

```
hive -e "SELECT d.*, 
MIN(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS MIN_YEARLY, 
MAX(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_YEARLY, 
AVG(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS AVG_YEARLY, 
STDDEV(HIGH) OVER(PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS STD_YEARLY 
FROM NSEDATA d 
ORDER BY SYMBOL" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > ~/output2.csv
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876238/assign-same-value-when-using-lag-function-if-column-used-in-lag-has-same-value

Comment: @nmr Answered, please check